# Running a UNIX command via python script

Tags: python, unix

I have to execute this following command

`exec /dir6/dir5/dir4/openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -in /home/dir2/dir3/XXX.enc -pass pass:password`

from my python Script. 
I have used

`subprocess.call(["exec"," /dir6/dir5/dir4/openssl","enc","-d","-aes-256-cbc","-a","-in","/home/dir2/dir3/XXX.enc","-pass", "pass:password"])`

but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It gives me the below mentioned error as before:


`File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 478, in call
    p = Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 642, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1234, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need "exec" here, and there is an unneeded space before `/dir6` :

```
subprocess.call(['/dir6/dir5/dir4/openssl', 'enc', '-d', '-aes-256-cbc', '-a', '-in', '/home/dir2/dir3/XXX.enc' ,'-pass' , 'pass:password'])
```

I assumed that your command works, but I could not find the `-pass` option in the openssl manual.

Comment: Thanks for the answer JBzh.
Please see the error i just mentioned, hope u can help me more on this now.

Comment: did you removed the space in " /dir6/dir5/dir4/openssl" ? does the file /dir6/dir5/dir4/openssl exists ?

Comment: Yes i have tried after removing the space too. & yes the file exists as that command  is executing in a tcl script already.

Comment: what is the output of this command if your execute it from your shell directly ? Not inside your python script and not from your TCL script, directly from the shell : /dir6/dir5/dir4/openssl . You removed 'exec' too, as stated in my answer ?

Comment: `/dir6/dir5/dir4/openssl`
or 
`exec /dir6/dir5/dir4/openssl`

Error: Command not found

`cd /dir6/dir5/dir4/openssl`
Error: No such file or directory

Comment: then this is what's wrong, this file does not exists : /dir6/dir5/dir4/openssl . If you can use the standard openssl of your system, then just use  `subprocess.call(['openssl', 'enc', '-d', '-aes-256-cbc', '-a', '-in', '/home/dir2/dir3/XXX.enc' ,'-pass' , 'pass:password'])`